# How to set SOAPUI property value with time + x minutes using groovy?

Tags: groovy, soapui

I want to to set Property value in SOAPUI with current time + 5 minutes

i tried this:

```
import groovy.time.*
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.TimeCategory
import groovy.time.TimeCategory
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

currentDate =  new Date()
use( TimeCategory ) {
   after30Mins  = date + 30.minutes
}
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue( "SendHour",after30Mins)
log.info (after30Mins)
```

I got this error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlProject.setPropertyValue() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.util.Date) values: [SendHour, Sun Jun 07 19:37:52 EDT 2015] Possible solutions: setPropertyValue(java.lang.String, java.lang.String), getPropertyValue(java.lang.String) error at line: 10
```

Any help please, Thank you

Answer (score 2):

As the error message says, the method `setPropertyValue` takes 2 parameters, both od them `String`. So the solution is to cast the `after3OMins` variable to `String`. In Groovy, `Date` implements the `format` method that makes casting to `String` really easy. In our case it could look like

```
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue( "SendHour", 
after30Mins.format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"))
```